# What makes this WHILE LOOP in Postgres throw an error?

Tags: sql, postgresql, while-loop

My query is for inserting many rows with slight data variations. By using a temp table I can approximate user variables but when I add the loop I get this error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHILE"

Please help with syntax:

```
-- SQL User Variables in temp table

        create temporary table foo as select 1108 as udocid, CAST('2018-01-01' as date)as uctime, CAST('2018-01-15'as date)as umtime,'Study1108' as udocname, 'xlsx' as udoctype, 'C:\2018Studies\Data' as udocpath;
     --Here is the erroring WHILE condition:   
        WHILE foo.udocid < 1110  LOOP

         INSERT INTO documents(docid,ctime,mtime,docname,doctype,docpath) SELECT udocid,uctime,umtime,udocname,udoctype,udocpath from foo;
         UPDATE foo SET udocid = udocid +1, uctime = (uctime + INTERVAL '1 day'), umtime = (uctime + INTERVAL '15 day'), udocname = CONCAT('Study', udocid),udocpath = CONCAT('C:\','2018Studies\','Data');

         -- loop inserts a row then updates the variables for the next row;
        END LOOP;
        -- clean up 
        drop table foo;
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHILE"
LINE 4: WHILE foo.udocid != 1110 LOOP
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 208

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no `while` in [SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql.html). If you need one, you need to use [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html)

But you don't need a loop or even a temp table for this in Postgres. Postgres has a handy function `generate_series()` which can be used to do what you want.

```
INSERT INTO documents(docid, ctime, mtime, docname, doctype, docpath) 
SELECT t.id + 1108, 
       date '2018-01-01' + t.id, 
       DATE '2018-01-15' + t.id * 15, 
       'Study'||to_char(1108 + t.id, 'FM99999'), 
       'xlsx', 
       'C:\2018Studies\Data'
from generate_series(0, 2) as t(id)
```

Comment: I do need to use a loop and the table takes the place of user defined variables that are missing in function. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-loop-statements/

Comment: Thanks for the generate series function I'll look into it but it can't CONCAT with the other variables and I want to increment dates too

Comment: @MacAries: of course you can use that to add values to the start date, see my edit

Comment: nice edit just TO_CHAR needs a mask:  'Study'||TO_CHAR(t.id + 1114,'FM99999'),